# How To Stop Entity Framework From Auto Number Primary Key

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first

I'm seeding a new EF 6 database from existing data that counts on the primary key values.  That is, I have two tables:

```
Sessions:  { Id int, Title String, Speakers: [x,y,z ints] }
Speakers:  { Id int, Name String }
```

I first seed all the speakers and unfortunately EF disregards the Id's I put in for the speakers, so when the Sessions are created, the SpeakerId's in the sessions are all wrong.

How can I get the primary keys form my speakers data to get inserted as the original primary key values from that data and not auto numbered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need 3 tables, not 2.

```
Sessions: {int Id, string Title}
Speakers: {int Id, string Name}
and
SessionsSpeakers: { int sessionId, int speakerId }
```

After that, then when you set up your data classes, you set it up like this:

```
var speaker1=new Speaker {Name="Me"};
var speaker2=new Speaker {Name="You"};
var session1=new Session {Title="This"};
var session2=new Session {Title="That"};
db.Speakers.Add(speaker1);
db.Speakers.Add(speaker2);
db.Sessions.Add(session1);
db.Sessions.Add(session2);
db.session1.Speakers.Add(speaker1);
db.session1.Speakers.Add(speaker2);
db.session2.Speakers.Add(speaker1);
db.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: EF creates the third table for me automatically.  Should I create that table myself?

Comment: No, that's fine then.

Comment: Thanks.  I get that it will work but my original data I'm importing already has Id's that I use for the cross reference.   Is there any way to preserve those id's?

Comment: Not easily.  You are using code first which hides the all complexity of table design, but then you want to use a table artifact.  They are sort of conflicting in designs.  Just design your code and keep track of them yourself, like in a dictionary, then let EF create and use it's own ids.

Comment: `Dictionary<int,Speaker> speakerDict(); Dictionary<int,Session> sessionDict();` as you create a speaker, add it to the speakerDict using your old id, and then add it to the db.Speakers collection.  Repeat for sessions.  Then when you process your old cross reference table, just grab the speaker and session using your old ids, and add the speaker to the session.  Of course this only works for a one-time bulk insert.  The old ids aren't saved anywhere.

Comment: Thanks Robert.  I'll go with that solution.